# rails 3.1 Engines Gemspec and config initializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

I am developing an rails 3.1 mountable engine. Build the engine very well and mounted it on a sub-domain. Now what i am having issue is that, in my `engine` `Gemfile` i specified a gem:

```
gem "show_for", "~> 0.2.4"
```

also in `.gemspec` file

```
s.add_dependency "show_for", "~> 0.2.4"
```

then i used engine's `script/rails g show_for:install` and it created a `initializer file` in config/initilizers directory.

When i go to `main_app` and run `bundle install` it shows that gem in the list. But when i start the application it show the error:

```
path_to_my_engine/config/initializers/show_for.rb:2:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant ShowFor (NameError)
```

How can we resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have to add: require 'show_for' at the top of your engine.rb file. I had a similar issue with my engine.